# Trouble Designing Programs in VBA

Tags: design, performance, vba

I am new to VBA and am struggling with overall program design:

**Toy Example**

Input: Spreadsheet with 20000 rows and 50 columns. Also, order of rows matters.

Task: Create 3 different reports on a new sheet. Computing these reports requires the following logic:

Filter rows based on criteria, perform computation with order of remaining rows in mind, filter more, perform computations, repeat 5-6 times.

```
Considerations:
    1. Runtime/Performance
    2. Readability/Maintainability of Code
    3. Provide formulas for end users in excel if possible (only when applicable)
    4. Error checking
```

***My question is which of the following approaches should I take for tasks like the one presented?***

**Approach 1** (Read Data into Variant Array):

I am under the impression that the fastest way to read in data is to an unallocated variant array as seen here:

Dim Arr() As Variant

Arr = Range("A1:A10")

After this, I can perform logic by accessing data such as Arr(1,3) and it is easy to filter this array by skipping rows that don't meet certain conditions. In terms of runtime, I think this a good approach. However, constantly accessing the array like Arr(1,3) makes code hard to understand (I suppose one method could be to assign some Constants to the column numbers). Also, with the Variant array, there is no type checking of inputs in each column. One source also mentioned that Variants can have overhead.

**Approach 2** (Read Data into Array of Types):

I can define a Type with attributes with appropriate data types. The major upside is that I think this method produces the most readable code as you can have meaningful attribute names with type checking. The major downside is that it is more difficult to write to worksheets and filter due to having to constantly resize arrays. Another downside I see is that the overhead increases runtime.

**Approach 3** (Use Worksheet functions and Temporary Columns):

The main benefit of this is providing some transparency to the end user in the form of formulas; also we can use built in worksheet functions that may help performance in some rare cases. There are two huge downsides to this approach. The first is that readability of code suffers tremendously as you have to properly format excel formulas in the code which can get out of hand with strings and other conditions. The second is huge performance bottlenecks. In a few runtime tests on toy examples, working with the worksheet outperformed the previous approaches; however, in my actual large programs things like AutoFilter can create 10 minutes delays. For the toy example above, I ended up having to create temporary columns and delete rows to create a report instead of filtering, close and reopen the input file, and start the next report.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your data is in Excel there is no point in copying it to variables first. You can just iterate over your cells instead and skip what you don't need (so much for filtering). You can start worrying about performance the moment it becomes a problem. You will have your logic straight and may be able to optimize. The same goes for readability and maintainability, improve as you go along and find it is getting harder.

Comment: If an autofilter is taking 10 minutes on 20k rows, the calculation logic is either enormously complex or enormously inefficient. Consider, are you limited to performing this work in VBA? It is generally considerably easier to perform the sort of work you describe in SQL, or maybe even using Excel's built in query-building tools nowadays.

Comment: @Steve I would much rather be using SQL here for the filtering logic. However, as order of the rows is important, would SQL be able to handle those conditions of comparing an attribute in one row to the row above and below it?

Comment: @OnMyCount, yes, any recent SQL engine can probably do that sort of comparison as a one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You listed already the major pros and cons of each approach - that is fine. The next step of the process is to compare these trade-offs against the requirements from your **real world situation** - hypothetical toy examples are unsuitable for this.

Assumed you want to create a solution which is going to be maintained and extended over a certain period of time, start **with the most readable and cleanest solution you can come up with**. According to what you wrote, I think approach #2 goes into this direction. Then, take **real data**, run your real code and

- **test** if the error checking / input validation is sufficient
- do **acceptance tests** with some end users.
- **measure** the performance, check if it is sufficient

If the tests show you something is missing or wrong, than fix it, but that is nothing where approaches #1 or #3 will usually help you with. In case  performance really turns out being not acceptable, *then* you should start thinking about improving it, not beforehand. So optimize the areas of the code where it really improves the results in a measurable way. Experimenting with ideas from #1 or #3 might help, but make sure you only sacrifice readability of your code when it is absolutely unavoidable to meet the performance goals.

Let me add a final word about *"Providing formulas for end users"*. This implies your end users want to edit the generated reports afterwards manually. This is something I would always question during a requirements analysis. Something which happens is that the reporting template has to change and users want to regenerate the reports for a given data set. Then every manual change to the reports they did afterwards will be lost, or will have to be transferred manually from the former version to the newer version. If you have reasonable end users, they usually understand why this is probably not what they want.

If your users really have requirements which don't allow to work differently, then go ahead with this approach. But I would heavily recommend trying to find a workflow where manual changes have only to be done in the **input data** of the process, and not afterwards in the generated **output data**. If you can define the process that way, there will be no need to have "formulas in the report" (which, to my experience, will result in a way more maintainable program).

Comment: *"When you explain this to your end users, they usually understand why this is probably not what they want."* - your users are very reasonable indeed. Mine usually wonder whether I can't just write the original without bugs, and update all their modified sheets for them! Sometimes however users want or need formulas and calculations because part of their role is to supervise or adjust automatically-generated results, or because training a user to interpret and reason about a report requires them to understand how it is generated.

Comment: @Steve: this is not primarily or exclusively about bugs, it is also about a changing requirements like a new reporting template (which usually is something the users can only blame themselves for). And that a report generator does not "automatically" update existing sheets is not really hard to explain to someone else. And yes, sometimes generated formulas make sense, exactly what I wrote in my answer- but one should not try to apply them whenever "they are applicable", as written in the original question, but use them when there is no way around them.

Comment: Ah, I wonder whether I've understood exactly what the OP proposes. When he said he intended to use worksheet functions and temporary columns, I gathered that he meant construct the logic by hand entirely in the worksheet using formulas rather than VBA code (which is a legitimate approach, especially if a user proficient with Excel but not VBA wants to be able to tweak calculations), not that he intended to generate and place the formulas themselves around the worksheet using VBA code <the horror!>. The latter implies significant complexity which can't be captured in the formulas anyway.

Comment: @Steve I would be using the worksheet to construct logic by hand so that it is visible in the end but I would be doing that with VBA as there would be many formulas (I know the horror). The user will be proficient at Excel and will be analyzing some results (audit but not change the logic). This makes me want to construct the logic in the worksheet; I still find this approach produces hard to read code. Also, at what point does this method fall apart? Formulas can get very long and hard to pick apart. Should I avoid formulas where auditing logic by manual calculation would be faster?

Comment: @OnMyCount, the trick with maintainable formulas in experience is to perform one operation or function call per column, and thus show the intermediary values (which are also then meaningfully named by the column header). I can only talk in generalities, but to need to generate and place formulas by code suggests two likely cases: one, that you are not sufficiently proficient with Excel to use all its lookup formulas and other functions to maximum effect, or alternatively, that the complexity of the calculation really is very high and (I'd suggest) something like SQL would be a better fit.